# Typescript shows error after wrapping a React component with withStyles and withTranslation HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-i18next, react-with-styles

I'm trying to write a React component using Typescript, `withStyles` from `@material-ui/core` and `withTranslation` from `react-i18next`. Both of this wrappers are HOC.

Typescript complains that there is an error about types.

For some reason this line does not work :

```
export default withTranslation()(withStyles(styles)(HomePage)); // error
```

However, if I use only withStyles or only withTranslation it works perfectly :

```
export default withTranslation()(HomePage); // ok


export default withStyles(styles)(HomePage); // ok
```

I know there is a problem about types, interfaces or maybe something wrong about exporting my components this way. 
I got the same problem when I used `withRouter` along with `withStyles`. I solved the error by changing their order in the export line ! (Didn't get why it was solved TBH)
I saw some solutions that suggest to wrap the whole component under `withStyles` but it seems ugly to me. Is there any suggestion ?

This is the error :

```
(alias) withStyles<"root", {}, {}>(style: Styles<Theme, {}, "root">, options?: {} | undefined): PropInjector<{
    classes: Record<"root", string>;
}, StyledComponentProps<"root">>
import withStyles

Argument of type 'ComponentType<Pick<IProps, "i18n" | "t"> & StyledComponentProps<"root">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<WithTranslation>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<IProps, "i18n" | "t"> & StyledComponentProps<"root">, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<WithTranslation>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<IProps, "i18n" | "t"> & StyledComponentProps<"root">, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<WithTranslation, any>'.
      Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<Pick<IProps, "i18n" | "t"> & StyledComponentProps<"root">> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<WithTranslation> | undefined'.
          Type 'WeakValidationMap<Pick<IProps, "i18n" | "t"> & StyledComponentProps<"root">>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<WithTranslation>'.
            Types of property 'i18n' are incompatible.
              Type 'Validator<{ changeLanguage: Function; }> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<i18n> | undefined'.
                Type 'Validator<{ changeLanguage: Function; }>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<i18n>'.
                  Type '{ changeLanguage: Function; }' is missing the following properties from type 'i18n': t, init, loadResources, use, and 28 more.ts(2345)
index.d.ts(80, 3): 'tReady' is declared here.
```

This is my component :

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
// i18n
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { InterfaceI18n } from "../../i18n";
// Stylus
import { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import styles from "./HomePage.style";

type WrapperPropsStylus = WithStyles<typeof styles>;
interface IProps extends InterfaceI18n, WrapperPropsStylus {}

class HomePage extends PureComponent<IProps> {
  changeLanguage = (lng: string) => {
    const { i18n } = this.props;
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };
  public render() {
    const { classes, t } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div>
          This is the home page (Public page) <br />
        </div>
        {t("Welcome to React")} <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.changeLanguage("de")}>de</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeLanguage("en")}>en</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation()(withStyles(styles)(HomePage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to solve this problem I changed the Component to Hooks.
Just use Hooks instead of Classes Components it's so much easier with TS.